# Calling multicase active pattern directly

Tags: f#, active-pattern

Consider a single case active pattern :

```
let (|ToUpper|) (input : string) = input.ToUpper();;
```

I can call the above single case active pattern outside an explicit  match:

```
let g ( ToUpper  x ) =x ;;
> val g : string -> string

g ("hello");;              
> val it : string = "HELLO"
```

If I have the following multicase active pattern :

```
let (|Even|Odd|) n =  if (n % 2 = 0) then Even else Odd ;;
```

How do I call the above multicase active pattern directly ?
The obvious way does not work :

```
let h ( |Even|Odd| n) = n;;
```

```
let h ( |Even|Odd| n) = n;;  
-------------------^
/home/shing/stdin(76,20): error FS0623: Active pattern case identifiers must begin with an uppercase letter
```

The reason for the above request is to write a test  on the active pattern, without  introducing a match explicitly.
At present, if I want to test the active pattern |Even|Odd|, I need to introduced the following 
isEven function.

```
let isEven n =
    match n with
    | Even -> true
    | Odd -> false


[<Test>]
let evenTest1()  =
    (isEven 6) |> should equal true
```

It would be nice if I could do :

```
[<Test>]
let evenTest1()  =
    (|Even|Odd| 6 ) |> should equal Even   // Does not work.
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Shing

Comment: Why would you want to? If you want to call directly, write a function. If you want both, wrap your active pattern with a function.

Comment: `let x = (|Even|Odd|) 6`

Comment: Note that you're not actually calling it "directly" with `g (ToUpper x) = x`, you're asking it to match something with a single case match. It's exactly the same as using discriminated union cases and tuples patterns in a definition, e.g. `g (x, y) = x`.